# Array element returning null in laravel-4

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to get records from a table using a given ID and I want to store specific columns into another array but I'm getting `null` every time I `var_dump()` my array.

My code:

```
$getOrder = array();
foreach($ordersInWaypoint as $ordersInWaypoints)
{
    $getOrder[] = array(
          array($ordersInWaypoints),
          array(Order::where('id', '=', $ordersInWaypoints)->get()->lists('tracking_id')),
          array(Order::where('id', '=', $ordersInWaypoints)->get()->lists('shipper_ref_no'))
    );   
}
```

For those wondering where $ordersInWaypoint came from, I retrieved that from here:

```
$ordersInWaypoint = array();
ordersInWaypoint = Transaction::where('waypoint_id', "=", $firstWaypoint)->get()->lists('order_id');
```

Don't mind the `$firstWaypoint` since that is determined by user input.

Everytime I `var_dump($getOrder);` I get the following result set:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 


array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 637
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
```

The first element is correct, but the rest return empty sets.

Comment: Those appears to be multiple arrays, are they empty at all even in sub-levels?

Comment: @phaberest Yes they are all empty but all the first elements of each array is stored.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you ordering a supposed-to-be single value with `lists()` and why twice? Are you trying to get the values you entered in `lists()` method?

Comment: @phaberest Correct me please if I'm wrong because I just started tutorials today for laravel and the way I understand the `lists()` method is after sorting out which specific data I want given a condition, I want `lists()` to retrieve THESE columns specified in `lists()`.. Do I have it all wrong?

Comment: Nope, `lists()` returns an array that contains values for only that column. Eloquent is made to simplify tasks like the one in your question and gives always objects in return. See my answer to understand what I mean ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting no value because those `Order::where(...)` return Eloquent objects, not just single values.

You could better try this way:

```
$getOrder = array();
foreach($ordersInWaypoint as $ordersInWaypoints)
{
    $order = Order::where('id', '=', $ordersInWaypoints)->get();
    $getOrder[] = array(
        array($ordersInWaypoints),
        array($order->tracking_id),
        array($order->shipper_ref_no)
    );   
}
```

Let me know if this fixes it ;)

#### Edit

It's even better if you don't use a multidimensional array as you need just these three values, so the final code becomes:

```
$getOrder = array();
foreach($ordersInWaypoint as $ordersInWaypoints)
{
    $order = Order::where('id', '=', $ordersInWaypoints)->get(); // create Eloquent object from query
    $getOrder[] = array(
        $ordersInWaypoints,
        $order->tracking_id,      // Calls column value as method from the Eloquent object
        $order->shipper_ref_no    // Same (you could also call it as an array,
    );                            // in that case you would type $order['shipper_ref_no']
}
```

Comment: What worked even better was when I just used `$order = Order::find($ordersInWaypoint);` I was able to grab anything I wanted under that id

Comment: Yup, I didn't think about it. That's the fastest way to get an element from its id ;)